# How to select a file on Mobile MIDP using J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I want to select a file on mobile using J2ME but I don't know way to do it. Help me, please !

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [FileConnection(JSR-75)](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) for this. See this links for your reference.

[How to Access Local File Systems from J2ME devices using FileConnection API](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-access-local-file-systems-from-j2me-devices-using-fileconnectio-2.html)

[File Connection Using J2ME api JSR 75](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-connection-using-j2me-api-jsr-75.html)

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is a file selection UI component, I'm afraid this does not exist by default in J2ME, and you'll have to create your own.

Such a component is planned for [MIDP3](http://www.j2mesalsa.com/midp3/fileselector.php), however good luck finding any devices which support it!